# Angularjs: restrict access to all pages except few

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router, jwt

I'm using Angularjs with ui-router and JWT(which is a tool for token based authentication) and want to implement authentication.

Say i want to restrict access to all my pages except three: "/home", "/about" and "/login". How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: A simple google search return [this](http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/) did you look at some of these posts?

Answer (score 3):

it's working ! enjoy :)

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngCookies','ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);

    scotchApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', function($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, current) {
            $rootScope.pageTitle = current.$$route.title;
            if (!Auth.isLoggedIn() && current.$$route.withLogin || Auth.isLoggedIn() && current.$$route.withoutLogin) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $location.path('/');
            }
        });
    }]);

    scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        // route for the home page

            .when('/list', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/list.html',
            controller: 'mainController',
            title: 'User List',
            withLogin: true,
        })

        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/register.html',
            controller: 'mainController',
            title: 'Register',
            withoutLogin: true,
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

bellow I'll explain for you how to protect access using angularjs Philosophy:

1- we supposed that you have factory named `verifyLogin` this factory used to verify if the user connect or not (inside this factory function named `isAuth`)

2 -file config contains the bellow code:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('docApp.doc_components_profiles', {
        needLogin: true,                
        url  : '/admin/page1',
        views: {
            'content@docApp': {
                templateUrl: 'app/admin/pages/profiles.html',
                controller : 'AdminController as vm'
            }
        }
    });
```

here you see that we write attribute named `needLogin` and we affect to this attribute value = true,in order to access to this path (admin pages) the user must be authenticated.

3 -now you can write as bellow to verify the path each time the user navigate from one to another

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
     if(toState.needLogin){
         if(verifyLogin.isAuth== false)
              {
              console.log("Ypou must connect before you access to this url!!");
               $location.path('/login');
              }
      }
}
```