# Angularjs: Some pages need restriction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt, restrict

I'm using Angularjs with stateProvider and JWT and want from user to logging before access to admin pages, otherwise he can access to other pages which didn't need an auth.

Comment: you can see my response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944474/angularjs-restrict-access-to-all-pages-except-few/34471550#34471550

Comment: thank you @Berguiga.M.Amine this is what I search :)